# Ruby YAML serialization and unserialization

Tags: ruby, serialization

I have a problem with Object-Oriented Project Hangman - serialization part. I saved my code in serialize method, but when I try to unserialize it, I have a problem with it. I see all components of classes in the YAML file and when I try to reach them with code, I can't do it. I don't know where the problem is. Here is my serialize method and deserialize method.

```rb
 def serialize
    file = File.open('game.yml', 'w') do |f|
      YAML.dump(self, f)
    end
    file.close
    exit
  end
```

```rb
def deserialize
 File.open('game.yml', 'r') do |f|
      p YAML.load(f)
    end
    # p file['word']
  end
```

If you want to see my all codes, here is my GitHub and Repl
Repl : https://replit.com/@Burakkepuc/Hangman#main.rb
GitHub : https://github.com/Burakkepuc/Hangman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's actually working fine.

`YAML.load` returns an **different** instance of Game.  You can call methods on that instance,  but you don't have any access to the properties.

```
def deserialize
 File.open('game.yml', 'r') do |f|
      loaded_game =  YAML.load(f)
      puts loaded_game.length # fails with method not found
    end
    # p file['word']
  end
```

add a reader to you Game class and then the above will report the value of the length in the newly load instance of Game.

```
attr_reader :length
```

I am not sure what you want to do with the loaded game, but perhaps you simply want to call `guess` on it?

```
def deserialize
 File.open('game.yml', 'r') do |f|
      loaded_game =  YAML.load(f)
      loaded_game.guess 
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What I want exactly is to reach documents inside YAML file such as word,split_words etc. I can make it with   `loaded_game.split_words` etc. I will fix a bit of my guess logic. But still, I have a problem while I was trying to reach word in YAML file. It is confused within `Game.rb` inside `word` variable. How can I reach inside my YAML file "word" variable ?

Comment: Okay I found the solution. Thank you for your help @nPn

Comment: I was going to say you could add an `attr_reader :word` and then use `loaded_game.word` to get the value,  but this all comes from the fact that you are dumping `self`,  that dumps the entire instance of the current game.  You might want to just create a hash with the values you want to save and load,  but dumping `self` is fine as long as you understand what you are working with.